# Rigging, moving feet affects the main body

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature

I'm trying to connect the armature to the feet of my model, but I want the feet to be able to move without affecting the main body in anyway, similar to how Kirby walks.

[image]

I tried assigning the armature to just the feet, the feet end up popping off the rest of the mesh (I removed the original screenshot to make room for a download link).

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could offer some advice on how to properly rig this model.

EDIT: I added a link to the Blender File if anyone wants to take a look at it.

**Blender File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0_pWAFE-Gd6d2phQ1ZZd0pCelk**

Answer (score 0):

So have the feet be controlled by the armature and nothing else? To do that you would have to go to pose mode and right click + shift on the bones that are for the foot, and then right click on that foot. Then press ctrl + p to parent it and click on automatic weights. If you had a single bone for the foot, you could avoid weight paint altogether and just click bone instead of automatic weights. I am not very good at weight painting so not gonna talk about that.

Also, currently the feet are a single model I think? If you are using the mirror modifier like I think you are, then apply it and then go to edit mode with tab. Then press p and click by loose parts. this will separate the feet into separate models which you can then select once you have left edit mode. To make these easier to move, you should probably go to object - transform - origin to geometry from the little pop out menu near the bottom of the screen.